# Could not load file or assembly Operation is not supported. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131515)

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2012, scheduled-tasks, coded-ui-tests

When I run CodedUI Test from a small Console tool via `vstest.console.exe` from a scheduled task I sometimes see this error message on different PCs:

> error : Could not load file or assembly 'file:///C:\foobar.dll' or
>   one of its dependencies. Operation is not supported. (Exception from
>   HRESULT: 0x80131515)

Why/what is this not supported?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

During my research I found that [this may happen when you downloaded a test in a ZIP from the internet and the advice was to unblock the ZIP](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/brada/archive/2009/12/11/visual-studio-project-sample-loading-error-assembly-could-not-be-loaded-and-will-be-ignored-could-not-load-file-or-assembly-or-one-of-its-dependencies-operation-is-not-supported-exception-from-hresult-0x80131515.aspx). But I copied the files over the network from my developer system to the test PCs and the files were not blocked.

Searching more for the error code `0x80131515` [I found this answer in the MSDN forum](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/695581ae-77e7-4c3a-bb3f-6472b8c47f65/sgen-could-not-load-file-or-assembly-file-or-one-of-its-dependences-operation-is-not?forum=msbuild#05f3d6fb-eefc-46db-8f90-430d21d4ba6f).

So I edited the file

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio
>   11.0\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TestWindow\vstest.console.exe.config

and added the entry `<loadFromRemoteSources enabled="true" />` under the runtime tag and voilá, the tests run fine without any issues from a scheduled task.

Maybe this helps other users who also run into this strange issue.

Comment: where can i find this config file in vs 10.0?

Comment: @user3373603 Have you checked "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TestWindow\vstest.console.exe.config"? But I'M not sure if VS2010 already has the file. I think here it only includes the old mstest.exe, so edit "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\MSTest.exe.config"

Comment: Does not work, but answer given by Raj works very well.

Comment: @Bravo next time read correctly, I also posted that unblocking zip is 1 solution **facepalm**

Answer (score 187):

[image]

Right click on the Dll and unblock it.

Comment: as I mentioned in my answer, this is one possible cause, but did not apply to me. File are copied via USB drive/network and not downloaded from internet.

Comment: If you have **multiple DLLs in ZIP file, you can use unblock on this ZIP file** before it is uncompressed. Then, you do not have to unblock each dll separately.

Answer (score 17):

As previously stated, a Zip file is blocked when downloaded from an untrusted site. If you are confident the site is reliable you can prevent this behavior by adding it to your trusted sites list in **Internet Explorer -> Tools Menu -> Internet Options -> Security Tab -> Trusted Sites**. Future downloads will not be marked as blocked.

For blocked files that have already been extracted, run this at a Powershell prompt to unblock all the files in the current folder and subfolders:

```
Get-ChildItem *.* -Recurse | Unblock-File
```

Comment: Thank you, other options create a security risk. Since the files downloaded for me come from OneDrive which is too generic to allow. The use of remote sources doesn't feel secure to me, due to opening up doors for bad practice. This PS script fixes all the issues.

Answer (score 10):

1) go to exe file click the properties

2) click the unblock button

then this will slove

Answer (score 0):

For me, I needed to set the start up object in the Application settings.

Right click on the project name in the Solution Explorer. Click Properties. Go to the Application tab, Select the correct method from the Startup object dropdown.

Mine was not set, causing intermittent compile errors.