# MsBuild failure when compiling test suite after checking out from Git repo

Tags: c#, msbuild

I have a test suite created in my local machine which builds without any issues using command prompt via msbuild. But when I try to compile the same after checking out from git repo, I get the following error. I tried opening the code from visual studio and building, I get the same error. Please help me to resolve this issue.

I tried deleting bin and obj folders but it did not resolve the error.
Visual Studio Community 2019
Path to git repo: https://github.com/umanga89/CSharp-SeleniumFramework

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
> Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Current\Bin>MSBuild.exe
> C:\Users\laksh\Downloads\CSharp-SeleniumFramework-master\CSharp-SeleniumFramework-master\SeleniumTestAutomationFramework.sln
> Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 16.6.0+5ff7b0c9e for .NET Framework
> Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
>
> Building the projects in this solution one at a time. To enable
> parallel build, please add the "-m" switch. Build started 6/29/2020
> 7:19:58 PM. Project
> "C:\Users\laksh\Downloads\CSharp-SeleniumFramework-master\CSharp-SeleniumFramework-master\SeleniumTestAutomationFramework.sln"
> on node 1 (default targets). ValidateSolutionConfiguration:   Building
> solution configuration "Debug|Any CPU". Project
> "C:\Users\laksh\Downloads\CSharp-SeleniumFramework-master\CSharp-SeleniumFramework-master\SeleniumTestAutomationFramework.sln"
> (1) is building
> "C:\Users\laksh\Downloads\CSharp-SeleniumFramework-master\C
> Sharp-SeleniumFramework-master\SeleniumTestAutomationFramework\SeleniumTestAutomationFramework.csproj"
> (2) on node 1 (default targets). UpdateFeatureFilesInProject:
> SpecFlowFeatureFiles: Features\GoogleSearch.feature   [SpecFlow]
> process: MSBuild, pid: 27012, CD:
> C:\Users\laksh\Downloads\CSharp-SeleniumFramework-master\CSharp-SeleniumFramework-master\SeleniumTestAutomationFramework
> [SpecFlow]   mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
> PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089   [SpecFlow]   MSBuild,
> Version=15.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a
> [SpecFlow]   System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
> PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089   [SpecFlow]   System.Core,
> Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
> [SpecFlow]   System.Configuration, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
> PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a   [SpecFlow]
> Microsoft.Build.Framework, Version=15.1.0.0, Culture=neutral,
> PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a   [SpecFlow]   Microsoft.Build,
> Version=15.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a
> [SpecFlow]   System.Xml, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
> PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089   [SpecFlow]   System.Memory,
> Version=4.0.1.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51
> [SpecFlow]   netstandard, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
> PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51   [SpecFlow]
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe, Version=4.0.4.1,
> Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a   [SpecFlow]
> System.Numerics.Vectors, Version=4.1.3.0, Culture=neutral,
> PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a   [SpecFlow]
> System.Threading.Tasks.Dataflow, Version=4.6.3.0, Culture=neutral,
> PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a   [SpecFlow]
> System.Collections.Immutable, Version=1.2.3.0, Culture=neutral,
> PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a   [SpecFlow]
> Microsoft.Build.Tasks.Core, Version=15.1.0.0, Culture=neutral,
> PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a   [SpecFlow]
> Microsoft.Build.Utilities.Core, Version=15.1.0.0, Culture=neutral,
> PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a   [SpecFlow]
> SpecFlow.Tools.MsBuild.Generation, Version=3.1.0.0, Culture=neutral,
> PublicKeyToken=0778194805d6db41   [SpecFlow]   TechTalk.SpecFlow,
> Version=3.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=0778194805d6db41
> [SpecFlow]   TechTalk.SpecFlow.Generator, Version=3.1.0.0,
> Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=0778194805d6db41   [SpecFlow]   BoDi,
> Version=1.4.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=ff7cd5ea2744b496
> [SpecFlow]   System.Net.Http, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
> PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a   [SpecFlow] Starting
> GenerateFeatureFileCodeBehind
> C:\Users\laksh\Downloads\CSharp-SeleniumFramework-master\CSharp-SeleniumFramework-master\packages\SpecFlow.Tools.MsBuild.Generation.3.1.86\build\SpecFlow.Tools.MsBuild.Generation.targets(93,5):
> error MSB4018: T he "GenerateFeatureFileCodeBehindTask" task failed
> unexpectedly.
> [C:\Users\laksh\Downloads\CSharp-SeleniumFramework-master\CSharp-SeleniumFramework-master\SeleniumTestAutomationFramework\SeleniumTestAutomationF
> ramework.csproj]
> C:\Users\laksh\Downloads\CSharp-SeleniumFramework-master\CSharp-SeleniumFramework-master\packages\SpecFlow.Tools.MsBuild.Generation.3.1.86\build\SpecFlow.Tools.MsBuild.Generation.targets(93,5):
> error MSB4018: T echTalk.SpecFlow.SpecFlowException: Unable to load
> plugin assembly:
> C:\Users\laksh\Downloads\CSharp-SeleniumFramework-master\CSharp-SeleniumFramework-master\packages\SpecRun.SpecFlow.3-1-0.3.1.48\build\net471
> SpecRun.Generator.SpecFlowPlugin.dll. Please check
> http://go.specflow.org/doc-plugins for details. --->
> System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly
> 'file:///C:\Users\laksh\Downloads\CSharp-Sele
> niumFramework-master\CSharp-SeleniumFramework-master\packages\SpecRun.SpecFlow.3-1-0.3.1.48\build\net471\SpecRun.Generator.SpecFlowPlugin.dll'
> or one of its dependencies. Operation is not supported. (Exception
> from HRESULT: 0x80131515) ---> System.NotSupportedException: An
> attempt was made to load an assembly from a network location which
> would have caused the assembly to be sandboxed in previous versions of
> the .NET  Framework. This release of the .NET Framework does not
> enable CAS policy by default, so this load may be dangerous. If this
> load is not intended to sandbox the assembly, please enable the
> loadFromRemoteSources  switch. See
> http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=155569 for more information.
> [C:\Users\laksh\Downloads\CSharp-SeleniumFramework-master\CSharp-SeleniumFramework-master\SeleniumTestAutomationFramework\Seleniu
> mTestAutomationFramework.csproj]
> C:\Users\laksh\Downloads\CSharp-SeleniumFramework-master\CSharp-SeleniumFramework-master\packages\SpecFlow.Tools.MsBuild.Generation.3.1.86\build\SpecFlow.Tools.MsBuild.Generation.targets(93,5):
> error MSB4018:   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
> [C:\Users\laksh\Downloads\CSharp-SeleniumFramework-master\CSharp-SeleniumFramework-master\SeleniumTestAutomationFramework\SeleniumTestAutomationFramework.csproj]
> C:\Users\laksh\Downloads\CSharp-SeleniumFramework-master\CSharp-SeleniumFramework-master\packages\SpecFlow.Tools.MsBuild.Generation.3.1.86\build\SpecFlow.Tools.MsBuild.Generation.targets(93,5):
> error MSB4018:   at
> System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly._nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String
> codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint,
> StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnF
> ileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks)
> [C:\Users\laksh\Downloads\CSharp-SeleniumFramework-master\CSharp-SeleniumFramework-master\SeleniumTestAutomationFramework\SeleniumTestAutom
> ationFramework.csproj]
> C:\Users\laksh\Downloads\CSharp-SeleniumFramework-master\CSharp-SeleniumFramework-master\packages\SpecFlow.Tools.MsBuild.Generation.3.1.86\build\SpecFlow.Tools.MsBuild.Generation.targets(93,5):
> error MSB4018:   at
> System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String
> codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint,
> StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFi
> leNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks)
> [C:\Users\laksh\Downloads\CSharp-SeleniumFramework-master\CSharp-SeleniumFramework-master\SeleniumTestAutomationFramework\SeleniumTestAutoma
> tionFramework.csproj]
> C:\Users\laksh\Downloads\CSharp-SeleniumFramework-master\CSharp-SeleniumFramework-master\packages\SpecFlow.Tools.MsBuild.Generation.3.1.86\build\SpecFlow.Tools.MsBuild.Generation.targets(93,5):
> error MSB4018:   at
> System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoadAssemblyName(AssemblyName
> assemblyRef, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly reqAssembly,
> StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throw
> OnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean
> suppressSecurityChecks)
> [C:\Users\laksh\Downloads\CSharp-SeleniumFramework-master\CSharp-SeleniumFramework-master\SeleniumTestAutomationFramework\SeleniumTestAu
> tomationFramework.csproj]
> C:\Users\laksh\Downloads\CSharp-SeleniumFramework-master\CSharp-SeleniumFramework-master\packages\SpecFlow.Tools.MsBuild.Generation.3.1.86\build\SpecFlow.Tools.MsBuild.Generation.targets(93,5):
> error MSB4018:   at
> System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoadFrom(String
> assemblyFile, Evidence securityEvidence, Byte[] hashValue,
> AssemblyHashAlgorithm hashAlgorithm, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean
> suppressSecurityC hecks, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
> [C:\Users\laksh\Downloads\CSharp-SeleniumFramework-master\CSharp-SeleniumFramework-master\SeleniumTestAutomationFramework\SeleniumTestAutomationFramework.csproj]
> C:\Users\laksh\Downloads\CSharp-SeleniumFramework-master\CSharp-SeleniumFramework-master\packages\SpecFlow.Tools.MsBuild.Generation.3.1.86\build\SpecFlow.Tools.MsBuild.Generation.targets(93,5):
> error MSB4018:   at System.Reflection.Assembly.LoadFrom(String
> assemblyFile)
> [C:\Users\laksh\Downloads\CSharp-SeleniumFramework-master\CSharp-SeleniumFramework-master\SeleniumTestAutomationFramework\SeleniumTestAutomationFram
> ework.csproj]
> C:\Users\laksh\Downloads\CSharp-SeleniumFramework-master\CSharp-SeleniumFramework-master\packages\SpecFlow.Tools.MsBuild.Generation.3.1.86\build\SpecFlow.Tools.MsBuild.Generation.targets(93,5):
> error MSB4018:   at
> TechTalk.SpecFlow.Generator.Plugins.GeneratorPluginLoader.LoadPlugin(PluginDescriptor
> pluginDescriptor)
> [C:\Users\laksh\Downloads\CSharp-SeleniumFramework-master\CSharp-SeleniumFramework-master\SeleniumTes
> tAutomationFramework\SeleniumTestAutomationFramework.csproj]
> C:\Users\laksh\Downloads\CSharp-SeleniumFramework-master\CSharp-SeleniumFramework-master\packages\SpecFlow.Tools.MsBuild.Generation.3.1.86\build\SpecFlow.Tools.MsBuild.Generation.targets(93,5):
> error MSB4018:   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
> [C:\Users\laksh\Downloads\CSharp-SeleniumFramework-master\CSharp-SeleniumFramework-master\SeleniumTestAutomationFramework\SeleniumTestAutomationFramework.csproj]
> C:\Users\laksh\Downloads\CSharp-SeleniumFramework-master\CSharp-SeleniumFramework-master\packages\SpecFlow.Tools.MsBuild.Generation.3.1.86\build\SpecFlow.Tools.MsBuild.Generation.targets(93,5):
> error MSB4018:   at
> TechTalk.SpecFlow.Generator.Plugins.GeneratorPluginLoader.LoadPlugin(PluginDescriptor
> pluginDescriptor)
> [C:\Users\laksh\Downloads\CSharp-SeleniumFramework-master\CSharp-SeleniumFramework-master\SeleniumTes
> tAutomationFramework\SeleniumTestAutomationFramework.csproj]
> C:\Users\laksh\Downloads\CSharp-SeleniumFramework-master\CSharp-SeleniumFramework-master\packages\SpecFlow.Tools.MsBuild.Generation.3.1.86\build\SpecFlow.Tools.MsBuild.Generation.targets(93,5):
> error MSB4018:   at
> TechTalk.SpecFlow.Generator.GeneratorContainerBuilder.LoadPlugins(ObjectContainer
> container, GeneratorPluginEvents generatorPluginEvents,
> UnitTestProviderConfiguration unitTestProviderConfiguration, IEnume
> rable`1 generatorPlugins) [C:\Users\laksh\Downloads\CSharp-SeleniumFramework-master\CSharp-SeleniumFramework-master\SeleniumTestAutomationFramework\SeleniumTestAutomationFramework.csproj] C:\Users\laksh\Downloads\CSharp-SeleniumFramework-master\CSharp-SeleniumFramework-master\packages\SpecFlow.Tools.MsBuild.Generation.3.1.86\build\SpecFlow.Tools.MsBuild.Generation.targets(93,5): error MSB4018:   at TechTalk.SpecFlow.Generator.GeneratorContainerBuilder.CreateContainer(SpecFlowConfigurationHolder configurationHolder, ProjectSettings projectSettings, IEnumerable`1
> generatorPluginInfos, IObjectContainer parentObjectContainer)
> [C:\Users\laksh\Downloads\CSharp-SeleniumFramework-master\CSharp-SeleniumFramework-master\SeleniumTestAutomationFramework\SeleniumTestAutomationFramework.csproj]
> C:\Users\laksh\Downloads\CSharp-SeleniumFramework-master\CSharp-SeleniumFramework-master\packages\SpecFlow.Tools.MsBuild.Generation.3.1.86\build\SpecFlow.Tools.MsBuild.Generation.targets(93,5):
> error MSB4018:   at
> SpecFlow.Tools.MsBuild.Generation.WrappedGeneratorContainerBuilder.BuildGeneratorContainer(SpecFlowConfigurationHolder
> specFlowConfigurationHolder, ProjectSettings projectSettings,
> IReadOnlyCollection`1 ge neratorPluginInfos, IObjectContainer
> rootObjectContainer)
> [C:\Users\laksh\Downloads\CSharp-SeleniumFramework-master\CSharp-SeleniumFramework-master\SeleniumTestAutomationFramework\SeleniumTestAutomationFramewor k.csproj]
> C:\Users\laksh\Downloads\CSharp-SeleniumFramework-master\CSharp-SeleniumFramework-master\packages\SpecFlow.Tools.MsBuild.Generation.3.1.86\build\SpecFlow.Tools.MsBuild.Generation.targets(93,5):
> error MSB4018:   at
> SpecFlow.Tools.MsBuild.Generation.GenerateFeatureFileCodeBehindTaskExecutor.Execute()
> [C:\Users\laksh\Downloads\CSharp-SeleniumFramework-master\CSharp-SeleniumFramework-master\SeleniumTestAutomationFramewo
> rk\SeleniumTestAutomationFramework.csproj]
> C:\Users\laksh\Downloads\CSharp-SeleniumFramework-master\CSharp-SeleniumFramework-master\packages\SpecFlow.Tools.MsBuild.Generation.3.1.86\build\SpecFlow.Tools.MsBuild.Generation.targets(93,5):
> error MSB4018:   at
> SpecFlow.Tools.MsBuild.Generation.GenerateFeatureFileCodeBehindTask.Execute()
> [C:\Users\laksh\Downloads\CSharp-SeleniumFramework-master\CSharp-SeleniumFramework-master\SeleniumTestAutomationFramework\Selen
> iumTestAutomationFramework.csproj]
> C:\Users\laksh\Downloads\CSharp-SeleniumFramework-master\CSharp-SeleniumFramework-master\packages\SpecFlow.Tools.MsBuild.Generation.3.1.86\build\SpecFlow.Tools.MsBuild.Generation.targets(93,5):
> error MSB4018:   at
> Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute()
> [C:\Users\laksh\Downloads\CSharp-SeleniumFramework-master\CSharp-SeleniumFramework-master\SeleniumTestAutomati
> onFramework\SeleniumTestAutomationFramework.csproj]
> C:\Users\laksh\Downloads\CSharp-SeleniumFramework-master\CSharp-SeleniumFramework-master\packages\SpecFlow.Tools.MsBuild.Generation.3.1.86\build\SpecFlow.Tools.MsBuild.Generation.targets(93,5):
> error MSB4018:   at
> Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.d__26.MoveNext()
> [C:\Users\laksh\Downloads\CSharp-SeleniumFramework-master\CSharp-SeleniumFramework-master\SeleniumTestAutomationFramework\Selen
> iumTestAutomationFramework.csproj] Done Building Project
> "C:\Users\laksh\Downloads\CSharp-SeleniumFramework-master\CSharp-SeleniumFramework-master\SeleniumTestAutomationFramework\SeleniumTestAutomationFramework.csproj"
> (default targets) -- FAILE D.
>
> Done Building Project
> "C:\Users\laksh\Downloads\CSharp-SeleniumFramework-master\CSharp-SeleniumFramework-master\SeleniumTestAutomationFramework.sln"
> (default targets) -- FAILED.
>
> Build FAILED.
>
> "C:\Users\laksh\Downloads\CSharp-SeleniumFramework-master\CSharp-SeleniumFramework-master\SeleniumTestAutomationFramework.sln"
> (default target) (1) ->
> "C:\Users\laksh\Downloads\CSharp-SeleniumFramework-master\CSharp-SeleniumFramework-master\SeleniumTestAutomationFramework\SeleniumTestAutomationFramework.csproj"
> (default target) (2) -> (UpdateFeatureFilesInProject target) ->
> C:\Users\laksh\Downloads\CSharp-SeleniumFramework-master\CSharp-SeleniumFramework-master\packages\SpecFlow.Tools.MsBuild.Generation.3.1.86\build\SpecFlow.Tools.MsBuild.Generation.targets(93,5):
> error MSB4018:  The "GenerateFeatureFileCodeBehindTask" task failed
> unexpectedly.
> [C:\Users\laksh\Downloads\CSharp-SeleniumFramework-master\CSharp-SeleniumFramework-master\SeleniumTestAutomationFramework\SeleniumTestAutomatio
> nFramework.csproj]
> C:\Users\laksh\Downloads\CSharp-SeleniumFramework-master\CSharp-SeleniumFramework-master\packages\SpecFlow.Tools.MsBuild.Generation.3.1.86\build\SpecFlow.Tools.MsBuild.Generation.targets(93,5):
> error MSB4018: T echTalk.SpecFlow.SpecFlowException: Unable to load
> plugin assembly:
> C:\Users\laksh\Downloads\CSharp-SeleniumFramework-master\CSharp-SeleniumFramework-master\packages\SpecRun.SpecFlow.3-1-0.3.1.48\build\net471
> SpecRun.Generator.SpecFlowPlugin.dll. Please check
> http://go.specflow.org/doc-plugins for details. --->
> System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly
> 'file:///C:\Users\laksh\Downloads\CSharp-Sele
> niumFramework-master\CSharp-SeleniumFramework-master\packages\SpecRun.SpecFlow.3-1-0.3.1.48\build\net471\SpecRun.Generator.SpecFlowPlugin.dll'
> or one of its dependencies. Operation is not supported. (Exception
> from HRESULT: 0x80131515) ---> System.NotSupportedException: An
> attempt was made to load an assembly from a network location which
> would have caused the assembly to be sandboxed in previous versions of
> the .NET  Framework. This release of the .NET Framework does not
> enable CAS policy by default, so this load may be dangerous. If this
> load is not intended to sandbox the assembly, please enable the
> loadFromRemoteSources  switch. See
> http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=155569 for more information.
> [C:\Users\laksh\Downloads\CSharp-SeleniumFramework-master\CSharp-SeleniumFramework-master\SeleniumTestAutomationFramework\Seleniu
> mTestAutomationFramework.csproj]
> C:\Users\laksh\Downloads\CSharp-SeleniumFramework-master\CSharp-SeleniumFramework-master\packages\SpecFlow.Tools.MsBuild.Generation.3.1.86\build\SpecFlow.Tools.MsBuild.Generation.targets(93,5):
> error MSB4018:   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
> [C:\Users\laksh\Downloads\CSharp-SeleniumFramework-master\CSharp-SeleniumFramework-master\SeleniumTestAutomationFramework\SeleniumTestAutomationFramework.csproj]
> C:\Users\laksh\Downloads\CSharp-SeleniumFramework-master\CSharp-SeleniumFramework-master\packages\SpecFlow.Tools.MsBuild.Generation.3.1.86\build\SpecFlow.Tools.MsBuild.Generation.targets(93,5):
> error MSB4018:   at
> System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly._nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String
> codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint,
> StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnF
> ileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks)
> [C:\Users\laksh\Downloads\CSharp-SeleniumFramework-master\CSharp-SeleniumFramework-master\SeleniumTestAutomationFramework\SeleniumTestAutom
> ationFramework.csproj]
> C:\Users\laksh\Downloads\CSharp-SeleniumFramework-master\CSharp-SeleniumFramework-master\packages\SpecFlow.Tools.MsBuild.Generation.3.1.86\build\SpecFlow.Tools.MsBuild.Generation.targets(93,5):
> error MSB4018:   at
> System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String
> codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint,
> StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFi
> leNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks)
> [C:\Users\laksh\Downloads\CSharp-SeleniumFramework-master\CSharp-SeleniumFramework-master\SeleniumTestAutomationFramework\SeleniumTestAutoma
> tionFramework.csproj]
> C:\Users\laksh\Downloads\CSharp-SeleniumFramework-master\CSharp-SeleniumFramework-master\packages\SpecFlow.Tools.MsBuild.Generation.3.1.86\build\SpecFlow.Tools.MsBuild.Generation.targets(93,5):
> error MSB4018:   at
> System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoadAssemblyName(AssemblyName
> assemblyRef, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly reqAssembly,
> StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throw
> OnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean
> suppressSecurityChecks)
> [C:\Users\laksh\Downloads\CSharp-SeleniumFramework-master\CSharp-SeleniumFramework-master\SeleniumTestAutomationFramework\SeleniumTestAu
> tomationFramework.csproj]
> C:\Users\laksh\Downloads\CSharp-SeleniumFramework-master\CSharp-SeleniumFramework-master\packages\SpecFlow.Tools.MsBuild.Generation.3.1.86\build\SpecFlow.Tools.MsBuild.Generation.targets(93,5):
> error MSB4018:   at
> System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoadFrom(String
> assemblyFile, Evidence securityEvidence, Byte[] hashValue,
> AssemblyHashAlgorithm hashAlgorithm, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean
> suppressSecurityC hecks, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
> [C:\Users\laksh\Downloads\CSharp-SeleniumFramework-master\CSharp-SeleniumFramework-master\SeleniumTestAutomationFramework\SeleniumTestAutomationFramework.csproj]
> C:\Users\laksh\Downloads\CSharp-SeleniumFramework-master\CSharp-SeleniumFramework-master\packages\SpecFlow.Tools.MsBuild.Generation.3.1.86\build\SpecFlow.Tools.MsBuild.Generation.targets(93,5):
> error MSB4018:   at System.Reflection.Assembly.LoadFrom(String
> assemblyFile)
> [C:\Users\laksh\Downloads\CSharp-SeleniumFramework-master\CSharp-SeleniumFramework-master\SeleniumTestAutomationFramework\SeleniumTestAutomationFram
> ework.csproj]
> C:\Users\laksh\Downloads\CSharp-SeleniumFramework-master\CSharp-SeleniumFramework-master\packages\SpecFlow.Tools.MsBuild.Generation.3.1.86\build\SpecFlow.Tools.MsBuild.Generation.targets(93,5):
> error MSB4018:   at
> TechTalk.SpecFlow.Generator.Plugins.GeneratorPluginLoader.LoadPlugin(PluginDescriptor
> pluginDescriptor)
> [C:\Users\laksh\Downloads\CSharp-SeleniumFramework-master\CSharp-SeleniumFramework-master\SeleniumTes
> tAutomationFramework\SeleniumTestAutomationFramework.csproj]
> C:\Users\laksh\Downloads\CSharp-SeleniumFramework-master\CSharp-SeleniumFramework-master\packages\SpecFlow.Tools.MsBuild.Generation.3.1.86\build\SpecFlow.Tools.MsBuild.Generation.targets(93,5):
> error MSB4018:   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
> [C:\Users\laksh\Downloads\CSharp-SeleniumFramework-master\CSharp-SeleniumFramework-master\SeleniumTestAutomationFramework\SeleniumTestAutomationFramework.csproj]
> C:\Users\laksh\Downloads\CSharp-SeleniumFramework-master\CSharp-SeleniumFramework-master\packages\SpecFlow.Tools.MsBuild.Generation.3.1.86\build\SpecFlow.Tools.MsBuild.Generation.targets(93,5):
> error MSB4018:   at
> TechTalk.SpecFlow.Generator.Plugins.GeneratorPluginLoader.LoadPlugin(PluginDescriptor
> pluginDescriptor)
> [C:\Users\laksh\Downloads\CSharp-SeleniumFramework-master\CSharp-SeleniumFramework-master\SeleniumTes
> tAutomationFramework\SeleniumTestAutomationFramework.csproj]
> C:\Users\laksh\Downloads\CSharp-SeleniumFramework-master\CSharp-SeleniumFramework-master\packages\SpecFlow.Tools.MsBuild.Generation.3.1.86\build\SpecFlow.Tools.MsBuild.Generation.targets(93,5):
> error MSB4018:   at
> TechTalk.SpecFlow.Generator.GeneratorContainerBuilder.LoadPlugins(ObjectContainer
> container, GeneratorPluginEvents generatorPluginEvents,
> UnitTestProviderConfiguration unitTestProviderConfiguration, IEnume
> rable`1 generatorPlugins) [C:\Users\laksh\Downloads\CSharp-SeleniumFramework-master\CSharp-SeleniumFramework-master\SeleniumTestAutomationFramework\SeleniumTestAutomationFramework.csproj] C:\Users\laksh\Downloads\CSharp-SeleniumFramework-master\CSharp-SeleniumFramework-master\packages\SpecFlow.Tools.MsBuild.Generation.3.1.86\build\SpecFlow.Tools.MsBuild.Generation.targets(93,5): error MSB4018:   at TechTalk.SpecFlow.Generator.GeneratorContainerBuilder.CreateContainer(SpecFlowConfigurationHolder configurationHolder, ProjectSettings projectSettings, IEnumerable`1
> generatorPluginInfos, IObjectContainer parentObjectContainer)
> [C:\Users\laksh\Downloads\CSharp-SeleniumFramework-master\CSharp-SeleniumFramework-master\SeleniumTestAutomationFramework\SeleniumTestAutomationFramework.csproj]
> C:\Users\laksh\Downloads\CSharp-SeleniumFramework-master\CSharp-SeleniumFramework-master\packages\SpecFlow.Tools.MsBuild.Generation.3.1.86\build\SpecFlow.Tools.MsBuild.Generation.targets(93,5):
> error MSB4018:   at
> SpecFlow.Tools.MsBuild.Generation.WrappedGeneratorContainerBuilder.BuildGeneratorContainer(SpecFlowConfigurationHolder
> specFlowConfigurationHolder, ProjectSettings projectSettings,
> IReadOnlyCollection`1 ge neratorPluginInfos, IObjectContainer
> rootObjectContainer)
> [C:\Users\laksh\Downloads\CSharp-SeleniumFramework-master\CSharp-SeleniumFramework-master\SeleniumTestAutomationFramework\SeleniumTestAutomationFramewor k.csproj]
> C:\Users\laksh\Downloads\CSharp-SeleniumFramework-master\CSharp-SeleniumFramework-master\packages\SpecFlow.Tools.MsBuild.Generation.3.1.86\build\SpecFlow.Tools.MsBuild.Generation.targets(93,5):
> error MSB4018:   at
> SpecFlow.Tools.MsBuild.Generation.GenerateFeatureFileCodeBehindTaskExecutor.Execute()
> [C:\Users\laksh\Downloads\CSharp-SeleniumFramework-master\CSharp-SeleniumFramework-master\SeleniumTestAutomationFramewo
> rk\SeleniumTestAutomationFramework.csproj]
> C:\Users\laksh\Downloads\CSharp-SeleniumFramework-master\CSharp-SeleniumFramework-master\packages\SpecFlow.Tools.MsBuild.Generation.3.1.86\build\SpecFlow.Tools.MsBuild.Generation.targets(93,5):
> error MSB4018:   at
> SpecFlow.Tools.MsBuild.Generation.GenerateFeatureFileCodeBehindTask.Execute()
> [C:\Users\laksh\Downloads\CSharp-SeleniumFramework-master\CSharp-SeleniumFramework-master\SeleniumTestAutomationFramework\Selen
> iumTestAutomationFramework.csproj]
> C:\Users\laksh\Downloads\CSharp-SeleniumFramework-master\CSharp-SeleniumFramework-master\packages\SpecFlow.Tools.MsBuild.Generation.3.1.86\build\SpecFlow.Tools.MsBuild.Generation.targets(93,5):
> error MSB4018:   at
> Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute()
> [C:\Users\laksh\Downloads\CSharp-SeleniumFramework-master\CSharp-SeleniumFramework-master\SeleniumTestAutomati
> onFramework\SeleniumTestAutomationFramework.csproj]
> C:\Users\laksh\Downloads\CSharp-SeleniumFramework-master\CSharp-SeleniumFramework-master\packages\SpecFlow.Tools.MsBuild.Generation.3.1.86\build\SpecFlow.Tools.MsBuild.Generation.targets(93,5):
> error MSB4018:   at
> Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.d__26.MoveNext()
> [C:\Users\laksh\Downloads\CSharp-SeleniumFramework-master\CSharp-SeleniumFramework-master\SeleniumTestAutomationFramework\Selen
> iumTestAutomationFramework.csproj]
>
> ```
> 0 Warning(s)
> 1 Error(s)
> ```
>
> Time Elapsed 00:00:01.16
>
> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
> Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Current\Bin>

Comment: `System.NotSupportedException: An attempt was made to load an assembly from a network location which would have caused the assembly to be sandboxed in previous versions of the .NET Framework.`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Could not load file or assembly Operation is not supported. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131515)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34400546/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-operation-is-not-supported-exception-from-hres)

Comment: @mortb your suggestion fixed my issue for building it via msbuild. Thank you for that. But I still cannot build it using VS 2019. Any idea on that?

Comment: Does it make any difference if you run visual studio as Administrator? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/user-permissions-and-visual-studio?view=vs-2019#run-visual-studio-as-an-administrator