# Not able to load .net DLL targeted for 64-bit platform only

Tags: javonet

Below is the exception being thrown:

```
com.javonet.api.NException: Could not load file or assembly 'file:///C:\downloads\UrlNomalization\Microsoft.Bing.HashUtil.dll' or one of its dependencies. Operation is not supported. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131515)
        at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly._nLoad(Unknown Source)
        at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoadAssemblyName(Unknown Source)
        at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoadFrom(Unknown Source)
        at System.Reflection.Assembly.LoadFrom(Unknown Source)
        at SicsClrController.Engine.ClrEngine.LoadAssembly(Unknown Source)
        at SicsClrController.Engine.ClrEngine.processCommand(Unknown Source)
        at com.javonet.internal.BinaryStreamProtocol.executeCommand(Unknown Source)
        at com.javonet.internal.GatewayManager.loadAssembly(Unknown Source)
        at com.javonet.Javonet.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
        at Hello.main(Hello.java:20)
```

My system settings:

IntelliJ IDEA 2020.2.2 (Ultimate Edition)
Build #IU-202.7319.50, built on September 14, 2020
Licensed to IntelliJ IDEA Evaluator
Expiration date: October 25, 2020
Runtime version: 11.0.8+10-b944.31 amd64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o.
Windows 10 10.0
GC: ParNew, ConcurrentMarkSweep
Memory: 1971M
Cores: 8

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45221477/17034

Answer (score 0):

Actually, my .net dll was blocked (since came from 3rd party) by windows, unblocking this file solved the issue.