# Cant import a module due to "Import-Module : Could not load file or assembly" however the file is present

Tags: powershell, powershell-module, aws-powershell

Cant import the module due to the error below, but that file is present.

```
C:\Users\User.Name> Import-Module AWS.Tools.S3
Import-Module : Could not load file or assembly 'file:///C:\Users\User.Name\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\AWS.Tools.Common\4.1.12.0\AWSSDK.Core.dll' or one of its dependencies. Operation is not supported. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131515)
At line:1 char:1
+ Import-Module AWS.Tools.S3
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Import-Module], FileLoadException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : FormatXmlUpdateException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ImportModuleCommand
```

Also tried Add-Type -Path to the file, but same error.

Does anybody know what I can try and do to fix this?

Comment: I had the same issue. Looking for a solution

Comment: @YuMei this solved my problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34400546/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-operation-is-not-supported-exception-from-hres