# Could not load .dll file in powershell

Tags: powershell, webdriver, dllimport

I an trying to load the webdriver.dll file in my powershell ISE, But its saying that the working directory is invalid. If you could someone help me to load the driver that much appreciated.

[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/254T1.png)

Regards
Ananth

## Your working directory

```
$workingPath = 'C:\Selenium'

# Add the working directory to the environment path.
# This is required for the ChromeDriver to work.
if (($env:Path -split ';') -notcontains $workingPath) {
    $env:Path += ";$workingPath"
}

Add-Type -Path "$($workingPath)\WebDriver.dll"
```

Comment: Did you unblock the file? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34400546/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-operation-is-not-supported-exception-from-hres

Comment: Please post the error message as text - it will help other people find this question if they have the same problem. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question for more details

Comment: PowerShell ISE will be deprecated [PowerShell ISE is no longer in active feature development](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/windows-powershell/ise/introducing-the-windows-powershell-ise?view=powershell-7)